# Wordpress: How to get a thumbnail post plugin to work

Tags: wordpress

I need a second opinion on something.  I am trying to use the WP Post plugin as described in the following link:

http://www.seoadsensethemes.com/wordpress-wp-post-thumbnail-plugin/

You will see a section toward the bottom stating that you can call the feature using the following code:

```
$Wppt->get_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'post-thumbnail-square' );
```

It shows the following example inserted into the post loop:

```
    <!-- wp post thumbnail -->

<?php if ( function_exists( "$Wppt->get_post_thumbnail" ) ) {

$thumb = $Wppt->get_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail-custom-key-name' );

if ( !empty( $thumb ) ) { ?>

<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>"><img class="thumbnail" src="<?php echo $thumb['url']; ?>" title="<?php echo $thumb['title']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $thumb['alt']; ?>" width="<?php echo $thumb['width']; ?>" height="<?php echo $thumb['height']; ?>" /></a>

<?php }
} ?>

<!-- wp post thumbnail -->
```

I cannot get this to work.  Can someone tell me how this should specifically be used?  I am simply pasting  the code above  my loop on the default theme, replacing the 'thumbnail-custom-key-name' with the one assigned to my thumbnail. Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: What post are you trying to display a thumbnail from?
Is the $post variable actually set outside the loop?

Comment: I am trying to display a thumbnail for every post within the post loop.  The code above is pasted within the post loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code it looks like you're using a default value `'thumbnail-custom-key-name'` is that the name of an actual preset you've made?

Comment: Can you tell me the name of one of your presets?